Typescript for Chrome Extension: Property 'OnInstalledReason' does not exist on type 'typeof runtime'.ts(2339)
Installed chrome-types
npm i chrome-types

In background.js I check the install reason
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(details => {
  if (details.reason === chrome.runtime.OnInstalledReason.INSTALL) {
    // foo
  }
});

But TypeScript gives error:
Property 'OnInstalledReason' does not exist on type 'typeof runtime'.ts(2339)

Official documentation says it is available
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/runtime#type-OnInstalledReason
Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

You might want to open an issue on their repo instead of here, pointing out that their own example does not work.
